# Surface Pro 7 & Miracast

Tags: windows, microsoft-surface-pro, miracast

I am uncertain if this is the correct forum but here is my question:

I have repeatedly tried to get miracast to work properly with my Samsung KS8000 55in tv. When I connect wirelessly, I can see the display on the tv for a short period of time being able to interact with it. However, after 2-5 mins the display will freeze and I can no longer use the display. On my device, the primary screen works but the casted second display freezes and I cannot use it anymore until I disconnect and reconnect. To also add that there is considerable mouse lag when it does work. I would like help to determine if I have a system software issue or if it is my tv no longer responding.

Comment: Have you tried to isolate the tab and the computer on its own network, the behavior you describe, seems to suggest interference or high latency within the network.  What is the latency between the computer and the TV?

Comment: How would I be able to check the latency? Both are connected via ethernet to the router

Comment: You could get a general idea by pinging the device.